# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n^3+1}}$convergent/divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Please could someone help prove $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n^3+1}}$$ converges/diverges?

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried the condition convergence implies $a_n\Rightarrow 0$??

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: Of course $a_n\to 0$ !! indeed $$...=\frac{1+\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt n\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^3}}}\to 0\text{ if }n\to\infty $$

Comment: @idm : Of course i know that... I was expecting reply from OP...

Comment: I'm afraid that with your last edit, nobody can help you. The sum is divergent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n>0$ you have:
$$\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n^3+1}} \geq \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^3+1}} \geq \frac{n}{\sqrt{2n^3}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$

But the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{2}}$ is divergent, so series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n^3+1}}$ is also divergent.

Answer (score 2):

$n+1\sim n$ and $\sqrt{n^3+1}\sim n^{3/2}$ hence $$\dfrac{n+1}{\sqrt{n^3+1}}\sim \dfrac{n}{n^{3/2}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt n}$$

Since $\sum \dfrac{1}{\sqrt n}$ diverge, then $\sum \dfrac{n+1}{\sqrt{n^3+1}}$ diverge.

Answer (score 0):

- $\displaystyle n^{3}+n^{2} \geq n^{3}+1 \implies \frac{1}{n^{3}+n^{2}} \leq \frac{1}{n^{3}+1}$
- $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n\sqrt{n+1}} \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n+1}{n \sqrt{n+1}} \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n^{3}+1}}$
- $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ diverges